# How find the limit $I=\lim_{m\to 0,n\to 0}(m^2-2n)^n$

Tags: limits

find the limit

> $$I=\lim_{n\to 0}\lim_{m\to 0}(m^2-2n)^n$$

**my try:**

> $$I=\lim_{n\to 0}(0^2-2n)^n=\lim_{n\to 0}(-2n)^n$$ is not exsit,

my try is  true? Thank you

Comment: why download? Thank you

Comment: No, $\lim_{n \to 0} (-2n)^n$ exists and is equal to $1$. Consider $m=\sqrt{2n}$ and $m=\sqrt{3n}$, for instance.

Comment: Thank you $\lim_{n\to \infty}(-2n)^n$,for $y=x^x$,we must have $x>0$

Comment: and I think we can't let $m=\sqrt{2n}$,or $m=\sqrt{3n}$ ,because this is not $(m,n)\to (0,0)$

Comment: Oops, you are right (about your first comment). But then your expression is not defined for those values. This is different from nonexistence of limit.  
I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: I have edit,Now,Do  you understand?Thanks

Comment: In this form, you are right, "inner limit" is not defined for sufficiently small $m$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is not well-defined, i.e. the value depends on the choice of a sequence $a_j = (m_j, n_j)$ with $\lim_{j\to\infty} a_j = (0,0)$.
For example, $a_j = (\frac 1 j, 0)$ yields $\lim_{j\to\infty} F(a_j) = 1$ whereas $a_j = (0, \frac 1 j)$ produces undefined values and thus an undefined limit.